# Summation in a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

```
v0=1
alpha=1
t=0
dt=0.1
D = v0*dt
v = v0 - alpha*np.sqrt(v0)*dt
while v > 0:
    print(D)
    v = v0 - alpha*np.sqrt(v0)*dt
    v0 = v
    D = v0*dt
```

Using this while loop I print the value of D after each update. Is there a way to perform a summation within the while loop so that I print only the sum of all the D values instead of printing each D value as a distinct entity?

Comment: `D += v0*dt` ? keep a running sum on `D`.

Comment: We expect you to perform due diligence before posting a problem here.  Look up "Python running sum" on line and make an attempt first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just print it after your while loop.

```
v0=1
alpha=1
t=0
dt=0.1
D = v0*dt
v = v0 - alpha*np.sqrt(v0)*dt
while v > 0:
    v = v0 - alpha*np.sqrt(v0)*dt
    v0 = v
    D += v0*dt
print (D)
```

Comment: Do I need to swap the last two lines of the while loop to take into account v0*t before v0 is updated?

Comment: it depends how you want to sum it together. on first iteration you D already is initialized with v0*dt. so swapping last two lines would add your initial v0*dt value twice into D.

Comment: I understand. Well explained. Thank you.